# Mapping into firestore from React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to react and firebase/firestore.

I am trying to map into what I believe to be a nested firestore value. I am able to pull each value individually

```
function Pull() {

    const [blogs,setBlogs]=useState([])
  
    const fetchBlogs=async()=>{  
      const response=firestore.collection('customer');
  
      const data= await response.get();
  
      data.docs.forEach(item=>{
      setBlogs(data.docs.map(d => d.data()))
      console.log(data)
      })
    }
        
    useEffect(() => {
  
      fetchBlogs();
  
    }, [])
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
            blogs.map((items)=>(
                <div>
                    <p>{items[1].name}</p>
                    
                </div>
            ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have been trying to map twice to get into the string inside the collection, yet I have had no luck.

My FireStore collection

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Erfi2CVrBSbWocQXGR5PB_ozgg9KEu12/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are iterating a `data.docs` array and enqueueing multiple state updates then you will want to use a functional state update to correctly enqueue, *and update from* the previous state.

```
const fetchBlogs = async ( )=> {
  const response = firestore.collection('customer');
  const data = await response.get();

  data.docs.forEach(item => {
    setBlogs(blogs => blogs.concat(item.data()))
  });
}
```

or you can map the `data.docs` to an array of items and update state once.

```
const fetchBlogs = async ( )=> {
  const response = firestore.collection('customer');
  const data = await response.get();

  setBlogs(blogs => blogs.concat(data.docs.map(item => item.data())));
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Both examples work, I chose the first because I am enqueueing multiple state updates. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try changing the foreach to a snapshot like this:

```
data.docs.onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
  setBlogs(snapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
  console.log(data)
})
```

ive used it like this in the past multiple times
and it has worked. If it doesnt work, the instagram clone tutorial on youtube by Clever Programmer goes over this well.